# How to do an efficient random walk in arangodb?

Tags: arangodb, aql, random-walk

I am working on a graph database on ArangoDB and I'm trying to have paths through a random walk. My purpose is from a start vertex V, I get for instance 4 random paths with a specified depth.

As far as from now, I've found the following code that works :

```
FOR vertex, edge, path IN 4..4 ANY 'Vertex/417438' edge_collection OPTIONS {bfs: TRUE, uniqueVertices : True, uniqueEdges : True}
    SORT RAND()
    LIMIT 3
    FILTER  IS_SAME_COLLECTION('Vertex', vertex)
    RETURN path
```

This indeed gives me 3 paths with a depth of 4, but it takes quite a long time because of the SORT RAND() at the beginning. I guess it first sorts randomly all the possible solution and then returns the solution.

Do you think, there's a way to have random solutions that costs less time?

Thanks for your time and for your futures answers

Answer (score 1):

I've just discussed with someone from the dev Team of Arango. Getting a random node in AQL is not possible for the moment. It's in there roadmap however.

I found a way to do a random Walk on ArangoDB though.

Let's take `v`, the starting vertex.

1. Query the number of neighbors `N` of `v` with this command :

   ```
   FOR clip, edge, path IN ANY '${vertex}' hasClipped OPTIONS {bfs: TRUE, uniqueVertices : True, uniqueEdges : True}
                           COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO len
                           RETURN len
   ```
2. Then choose a random number `rd` between 0 and `N` and execute the following request :

   ```
   FOR obj IN ANY '${vertex}' hasClipped OPTIONS {bfs : true, uniqueVertices : 'path'}
                           LIMIT ${rd}, 1
                           RETURN obj
   ```

   This request will return a random neighbor among the existing ones.
3. Iterate to get a random walk with the depth you want.